# Download file from S3 subfolder by dynamically setting the key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my S3 bucket, I have a folder structure of `rootFolder1/year/month/day/myfile.csv`. Depending on the time, the `rootFolder` folder could have multiple subfolder, organised by `year`, `month` and `date`, with each `date` folder containing multiple csv files. There could also be a `rootFolder2` in my bucket, with the same folder structure.

I know for downloading object from S3, I can use the `getObject` method where I can pass in the `params` object with the bucket `Key` like so:

```
var params = {
        Key: "book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv",
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-test'
    }

    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        // do something with data
    })
```

But in my case I don't want to hardcode the `Key` in. Is there any elegant way I can call `getObject` where I can dynamically set the `Key`, so it downloads the files under each `date` folder?

edit: for some further clarity, these are the keys I get back when I call `s3.listObjects`

```
  'author/',
  'author/2020/',
  'author/2020/01/',
  'author/2020/01/01/',
  'author/2020/01/01/all_authors_000.csv',
  'book/',
  'book/2020/',
  'book/2020/01/',
  'book/2020/01/01/',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_001.csv'
```

Comment: You'll have to list the objects for a prefix as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366708/get-list-of-objects-located-under-a-specific-s3-folder/52063453) and then download those that you want individually.

Comment: What do you mean by "downloads the files under each date folder"? Are you wanting to download _all_ objects in the bucket? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I mean downloading each of the `.csv` files